# Setting certain elements in listview not clickable

Tags: android, listview, clickable

To set certain elements of my ListView not clickable I use the isEnabled method in my Custom Array Adapter as following. The strange thing is that the items in the ListView itself are **displayed correctly, but** there are going some things **wrong with being clickable**.

What might helps is that when I scroll, suddenly the Toast comes up instead of in the beginning, giving a position which not corresponds with the element which should not be clickable and is displayed in Black.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        Object sRO = getItem(position);

        title = sRO.getTitle();
        description = sRO.getDescription();
        isBuffered = sRO.getIsBuffered();

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.jText);
            holder.tvDescription = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.jDescription);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk);

            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        }

        if (isBuffered == true) {

            holder.tvTitle.setText(title);
            holder.tvDescription.setText(description);
            holder.tvTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else if (isBuffered == false) {

            holder.tvTitle.setText(title);
            holder.tvTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.tvDescription.setText(description
                    + " - not supported");
            holder.tvDescription.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {



        if (isBuffered == false ) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "false and "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            return false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "true and "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            return true;
        }

    }
```